# How many shots is considered "much" for Nikon DSLR body?

Tags: nikon, dslr, used-equipment

I'm into purchasing used DSLR Nikon body, and I see that number of shots advertised is anywhere between 5k and 250k.

My question is, how much does this number relate to the overall quality and reliability of used camera body? My guess is it does relate some, but that much more important factor is how camera was used, in what environment, etc than how many shots were fired, but still, all other factors aside, does shot count matter much?

Comment: Your question title and your question body have different questions in them. The above linked to question and it's answer already cover the "how many shots..." part that is in your title and first part of the question.

Comment: I guess I wasn't really sure what to ask exactly, hence apparent difference between title and question itself. Linked question answers my question, too. Self-deleting my question.